# c# Search and get path from Filename

Tags: c#, file, path

I want to look for a file inside the existing logical drives connected, but when I do that, i end up with an string[], which i really don't know how to handle...
So what I'm trying to do here, is search in the "hard disc" drives which normally have the format FAT32 or NTFS... (please tell me if there are any others often used) And then, i get the "letter" for that drive, and tries to search for the csgo.exe file from there. And you can probably figure out the rest...

Here's my code...

```
if (d.DriveFormat.ToString() == "FAT32" || d.DriveFormat.ToString() == "NTFS")
{
    string StartDir = d.RootDirectory.ToString();
    String[] csgofile = Directory.GetFiles(StartDir, "csgo.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (String file in csgofile)
    {
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Drive: " + StartDir + ", CS:GO Path: " + file, "Path Found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You havent actually stated what your problem is.

A couple of points - when checking your DriveFormat do a string.Equals rather than '=='.

No point checking if the File.Exists, you know it does as you have just been given it from a live search.

You can check the length of the array returned, if its not empty you know you have your required file.

Now, please do actually ask a question / state the problem and we will try and help.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, you will end up on string[] since that is the variable you declare on this line:

```
String[] csgofile = Directory.GetFiles(StartDir, "test.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

If the file doesn't exist, and you debug it, it will look like

```
csgofile|{string[0]}
```

If it gets the file successfully, it will be:

```
csgofile|{string[1]}
```

Please take note that you are just searching the file on TopDirectoryOnly so make sure the file really exist in your the drive you are searching.

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept it as answer as reference to others as well. @Dotch